# Munin Aggregate Graphs from several servers

Tags: ubuntu, munin, graph

I am using DNS round robin load balancing and have divided my total traffic onto multiple servers. Each server does around 300-400req/second but I am interested in having an aggregate graph telling me the TOTAL of all requests per second served by our architecture.

Is there any way I can do this. Right now each graph in Munin comes as a separate graph as they depict things on one server.

I am using configuration as follow which doesn't work

doesnt work for me, does this configuration got errors?

```
[TRAFFIC.AGGREGATED]
  update no
  requests.graph_title nGinx requests
  requests.graph_vlabel nGinx requests per second
  requests.draw LINE2
  requests.graph_args --base 1000
  requests.graph_category nginx
  requests.label req/sec
  requests.type DERIVE
  requests.min 0
  requests.graph_order output
  requests.output.sum \
    lb1.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com:nginx_request_lb1.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com_request.request \
    lb3.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com:nginx_request_lb2.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com_request.request \
    lb3.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com:nginx_request_lb3.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com_request.request
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way look:

```
[ppke.hu;All_Totals]
  update no
  uptime.graph_title Uptimes
  uptime.graph_vlabel uptime in days
  uptime.draw LINE2
  uptime.graph_order \
    host1=host1.ppke.hu:uptime.uptime \
    host2=host2.ppke.hu:uptime.uptime \
    host3=host3.ppke.hu:uptime.uptime \
  uptime.graph_category system
```

I think you get the idea.

Later I replaced my munin monitoring with a more complete solution....

Comment: doesnt work for me, does this configuration got errors?

Comment: What did you replace it with?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can build aggregate graphs.

Here's the [how-to on the Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/aggregate_examples) site.

Basically, you create a fake node in your munin.conf, and the describe the sources, but it's easier to read the link than explain.

Answer (score 0):

Munin is *extremely picky* about hostnames and groups.  In your example replace TRAFFIC.AGGREGATED with something like <mydomain>;Totals

For example, check this answer from btm.geek: http://blog.loftninjas.org/2010/04/08/an-evening-with-munin-graph-aggregation/

```
[localdomain;2xLoad]
update no

dload.graph_title 2xload
dload.double.stack one=localhost.localdomain:load.load two=localhost.localdomain:load.load
```